# Adding multi language support in C++ Builder project

Tags: localization, c++builder, multilingual

Looking for a tutorial on how to add different languages to a C++ Builder application (otherwise known as localization).

I found a nice tutorial on how to do this using the Resource DLL Wizard on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3qe6gLNmGg

I can get this to work fine.
However at the 5:30 mark of the video, the topic turns to **switching languages at run time.**
The example shows how to do this using Croatian and English as the languages used and **there are some constants which are used** but I would like to know **where these constants are defined** for other languages.  (eg:  SUBLANG_CROATIAN_CROATIA, LANG_CROATIAN)  Would like to add German, French and Chinese to my application but don't know the constants I would need to use.

Currently using C++ Builder 11.1.5.

This video is over 10 years old so if this is an outdated way of doing this, could someone point me to an updated technique?

Comment: Those constants are defined in the Win32 API. You should have access to them without doing anything extra.

Comment: Remy,  Any particular file name?

Comment: They are defined in `winnt.h`, which is included by `windows.h`, which is included by the VCL for you. You could have found them yourself using the IDE's "Find in Files" feature to search the Win32 SDK includes folder. Or by simply typing one of the constants into your code and then Ctrl-Click on it, or right-click on it and choose "Find Declaration"

Comment: Thanks Remy.  In the header file it says that using these constants is now depreciated.  They still work but I am going to look at the SetLocale command and see how to do this.

Comment: Remy,  I noticed that the Resource DLL Wizard doesn't work with Firemonkey applications.  What's the way to do this?

Comment: FireMonkey doesn't support resource DLLs. I don't know how to localize FireMonkey without using 3rd party tools.

Comment: Remy,  I ended up using the TLang Component.  It's a little cumbersome at first but I managed to get it working ok.  When you pull up the editor in the TLang Component and scan for Strings, you have to have EVERY form open in the ide for your project, otherwise the scan procedure doesn't work.  

To change the language at run time, just use the SetLocale function and use one of the codes on this page (only first 2 characters are needed):
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Language_Culture_Names,_Codes,_and_ISO_Values

Comment: Remy, I discovered a very nice tool that someone has written called LangTool by oMAR.  It installs in the IDE and it can also be run as a standalone program.  It allows you to edit all the strings in your program in a spreadsheet environment and made my life a lot easier.  You can download it from:  https://github.com/omarreis/LangTool

Comment: Remy,  everything works as intended using the TLang Component, however the TMenuBar Component doesn't change languages.  A work around allowed me to do this manually via a routine I wrote which updates the menu items text property.  However, when you assign Chinese characters to the text of a menu item, the text appears as 2 Question Marks ??   Any ideas why this happens?  Other languages work fine (French, German, etc.)